# send email from a Microsoft exchange Imap account from MailCore

Tags: objective-c, imap, exchange-server, mailcore

Ok, so I am building an app that gets and sends emails from your email account, but I have hit a brick wall, the app worst great for POP3 accounts and IMAP accounts, but if are using a exchange IMAP account from a Microsoft Exchange server then it will let you log in and grab the unread emails, but not send anything, this is what i use to send an email

```
[CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:outMessage server:[dictData   valueForKey:@"SMTPServerName"] username:[dictData valueForKey:@"userEmailAddress"] password:[dictData valueForKey:@"password"] port:[[dictData objectForKey:@"SMTPPort"]intValue] useTLS:NO useAuth:YES];
```

And yes obviously the "username" is not always the email address. I have tried all different types of combinations of setting for the "useTLS" and "useAuth" part (YES/NO, NO/YES, YES/YES, NO/NO). I keep getting an error message back from mailcore saying the "username or password is invalid." --- this only happens when i try sending an email from that account

Comment: I am interested in this too. I suppose, you can't send via Exchange server, using SMTP protocol.

Comment: I ended up contacting the dude who wrapped mailcore he told me to log the communication between the server and the app, so use MailCoreEnableLogging() before you send the email and it will spit out everything you need to know, my problem ended up on the server of the client

Answer (score 0):

It is better (and more stable) to use separate SMTP class based on NSSockets
which does the same work as MailCore SMTP client.
NSSocket-based class will be more readable in locking for server connection errors.

We use MailCore only as IMAP part in our mail project.